# Binding datagridview with LINQ image column not showing image

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have used the following code to bind a datagridview using LINQ, but the image field is not displaying.

```
var query = r.GetTable<Subcategory>().ToList();

List<subcategory> l = new List<subcategory>();
foreach (var s in query)
{
    subcategory s1 = new subcategory();
    s1.sub_id = s.sub_id;
    s1.sub_name = s.sub_name;
    s1.sub_image =s.sub_image;
    s1.sub_catid = s.cat_id;
    l.Add(s1);
}

griditems.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
griditems.DataSource = l;
```

The image field is in binary format. It's not showing up, but the rest of the fields are displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Image` data type instead `byte[]`. You can convert `byte[]` to `Image` by this code:

```
public Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] imageBytes)
{
     System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageBytes);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```